# oracle datetime field indexing

Tags: oracle, indexing

How do we perform indexing on a datetime field in oracle. We should be able to search for a specific year

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To create an index in Oracle, use:

```
CREATE INDEX your_index_name ON your_table_name(your_column_name)
```

For more info about Oracle index creation, read [this link](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/indexes.php).

Correction & Clarification
If you use a function to isolate a component of a date (IE: [EXTRACT](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/extract.php), or [TRUNC](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php)), an index on the column will not help.  But an index will help if you provide a date range:

```
WHERE your_date_column BETWEEN TO_DATE('2010-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                                            AND TO_DATE('2010-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

You can however create function based indexes in Oracle:

```
CREATE INDEX your_index_name 
    ON your_table_name(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM your_column_name))
```

...which DBAs loath with a passion.

Answer (score 3):

You can index a DATE column (which stores date and time in Oracle) directly:

```
CREATE INDEX ix ON table (column)
```

Oracle will be able to use this index directly if you build your query so as to perform a RANGE SCAN. For example, if you want to retrieve rows from 2010:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM table
 WHERE column >= DATE '2010-01-01'
   AND column < DATE '2011-01-01'
```

This index can also be used to answer queries for a specific month, day or any other range.

Answer (score 0):

Add an index which is not bound to a column, but an expression that extract the year from that column:

```
create index sample_index on YourTable (extract(year from YourDateColumn)) tablesapce YourIndexSpace;
```

When you query the table using that expression, Oracle will use the index.

Answer (score 0):

Just create index like shown above. **DO NOT USE** `TRUNC` **FUNCTION**, because it ignores any indexes. For instance, my `datecreate` field has next format `03.12.2009 16:55:52` So I used to use

```
trunc(datecreate, 'dd')=to_date(to_char(sysdate,'dd.mm.yyyy'),'dd.mm.yyyy')
```

and it worked very slowly(about 5 sec)!!! Now I use next expression:

```
datecreate>=to_date(to_char(sysdate,'dd.mm.yyyy'),'dd.mm.yyyy') and sw.datecreate<to_date(to_char(sysdate+1,'dd.mm.yyyy'),'dd.mm.yyyy')
```

and my query executes in `0,01 sec`